# Azure Storage Explorer fails to upload files (stuck at Uploading Group)

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I try to upload files in a blob container using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, but it is stuck in the state :

> Uploading Group...

and nothing happens (no message, no error).

Comment: This should be moved to superusers as it is not related to programming.

Comment: @Murmel I think this tool is related to programming as it is a tool for developper, and not for power users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until a better solution, I found a workaround: use a previous version! (0.8.16)

You can download it there: [Download Azure Storage Explorer 0.8.16 (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-relnotes#version-0816-preview)

It seems this is a regression of the v0.9. [ISSUE - Storage Explorer](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/31917418-issue-storage-explorer-upload-files-does-not-w)

Answer (score 0):

Ther are two different ways to upload to Azure blob, Synchronous and asynchronous Upload.

**Synchronous Upload :**

The ICloudBlob method “UploadFromFile” doesn’t have any inbuild CANCEL mechanism for file upload.

**Syntax :**

```
public virtual void UploadFromFile(string path, AccessCondition accessCondition = null, BlobRequestOptions options = null, OperationContext operationContext = null);
```

**Asynchronous Upload :**

“UploadFromFileAsync” method of “ICloudBlob” has four overridden method’s, out of them three has an option of cancelling task while waiting to complete it. UploadFromFileAsync returns A Task object that represents the asynchronous operation.

**Syntax :**

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task UploadFromFileAsync (string path, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);


Example :

String filePath =@”c:\abc.txt”;
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
source.Cancel();
UploadFromFileAsync(filePath, token);
```

1] CancellationToken Propagates notification that operations should be canceled.

2] Instantiate a CancellationTokenSource object that generates a cancellation token, which can be assigned to CancellationToken for signaling CANCEL activity.

3] Then we can pass on CancellationToken to UploadFromFileAsync method. If “CANCEL” is called on CancellationTokenSource, then UploadFromFileAsync object in turn throws TaskCanceledException exception, which should stop upload.

**Alternate Options :**
We can implement UPLOAD functionality in a thread. On user clicking CANCEL, just Abort/Terminate that thread. But it does not guarantee whether file upload is cancelled or not, this will just help to close Application in time, it wont stuck in the state.